# Iframe not showing on all websites

Tags: html, iframe

In http://localhost i have put in the index.html file this:

```
<iframe src="https://google.com" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
```

But it just shows the sad face.

Any help would be good

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google.com prevents framing via the `X-Frame-Options` header.

Most large sites will do the same.

It's also possible to use a Content Security Policy to prevent framing.

Answer (score 1):

If you open [the JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console) in your browser you should see an error something like this

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

That means google's server is telling your browser not to allow displaying google.com in an iframe